# Django Rest Framework - Restrict FK entries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have 2 models, Post and Comments

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_post')
    ...
```

I have made a serializer for post

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all___'

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, source='comment_post')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_id', 'comments')
```

The PostSerializer gives all the comments on a particular post.

I want to access 5 latest comments per post. (planning to use something like order_by('-comment_time')[:5])

How can i do this in Django Rest Framework within PostSerializer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        # retrieve 5 comments
        return CommentSerializer(obj.comments.all()[:5], many=True).data 

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_id', 'comments')
```